# Problema entre proyectos de una misma solución

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo una solución que hasta hace unos días venía funcionando bien, entre otros, tiene un proyecto en ASP con .Net Framework 4.8 y acabo de cargarle un proyecto que usa .Net 5.0 La cuestión es que el proyecto en .Net 5.0 corre de lo lindo... pero el ASP en .Net framework 4.8 no da más... sin embargo no hay dependencias entre ellos, es decir, el proyecto ASP no tiene ninguna referencia al proyecto en .Net 5.0... y al ejecutar el ASP, el error que me tira me dice que el error está en el proyecto en .NET 5.0 ... ¿Tienen alguna idea de por qué pasa ésto?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Éste sería un extracto del mensaje de error:

Encerrado en rojo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]está el nombre del ensamblado que tiene .Net5.0 pero que no está referenciado en el ASP con Framework 4.8. Gracias.

Comment: En tu proyecto, verifica que la plataforma destino este seleccionado  .Net Framework, en una ocasión me paso que al generar un .net framework me cambio en todas las soluciones a .net Framework, en tu asp 4.8 da click en propiedades, en la pestaña aplicación verifica "Plataforma destino"

Comment: Cuando dices que el ASP en 4.8 "No da más", ¿qué significa? Es necesario que seas muchísimo más preciso con los mensajes de error, por ejemplo. Copia el texto, como texto, del mensaje de error y ponlo en tu pregunta. Edítala.

Comment: Gracias Fernando, también lo supuse y efectivamente el proyecto sigue en .Net Framework 4.8, lo cuál es correcto, pero el problema continúa.

Comment: @Alfabravo disculpa mi léxico florido. Con decir "No da más" significa que dejó de funcionar... agregaré un extracto del mensaje de error en la publicación.

Comment: @Alfabravo listo, ya actualicé la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: abre el nuget package y busca el siguiente paquete System.Runtime, ahi te aparecerá en que proyectos esta instalado, ve que sea la misma versión de tu proyecto, esta tratando de buscar un runtime Versión 5, degrádalo al 4.8 y recompila, espero te funcione

Comment: Gracias @Fernando, te comento que buscando en Nuget System.Runtime no me aparece en ningún proyecto instalado... sin embargo me diste la idea de buscar por el lado de la consolidación de paquetes de Nuget... intentaré por ahí.